# Raspberry pi:enable camera module

Tags: python, windows, camera, raspberry-pi

I have attached an usb camera with raspberry pi and also enable it using sudo raspi-config command . I rebooted the raspberry pi after enabling it, but it doesn't enable - so getting error (`error is..mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly`)

When run command (`raspistill -o image.jpg`) to capture an image, I have also run update and upgrade command to update raspberry pi but doesn't solve problem.

And main thing when I run `ffnpng -i /dev/video video.avi`, it records video so camera working so why this error coming? And what is the solution for that.

Is there any other way or command to cature image? plz help me. Thank u in advance.

Comment: Raspistill only works with the CSI camera module. You wrote that you are using a usb camera which is something different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the `fswebcam` module? You can get it using:

`sudo apt-get install fswebcam`

Images are taken using the command `fswebcam <image_name>.jpg`

A full tutorial can be found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/) from raspberrypi.org.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the connection between camera module and Raspberry PI CSI interface. Check if the CSI cable is correctly connected to CSI interface on the Raspberry PI board or try to unplug camera cable and plug it again.

**raspistillyuv** and **raspistill** are official image capturing programs for the camera module: [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md)

Answer (score 0):

USB cameras are not mounted under mmal (Only CSI). Try running `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` to see if your camera is mounted correctly. You will see there is a `/dev/videoX` like string under your camera if it's mounted correctly. Use that X value to access the camera.

As an example, in OpenCV(Python) you can capture an image as bellow,

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(X)
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite("image_name.jpg",frame)
cap.release()
```